# script for csvtool for replacing columns

Tags: scripts, csv

I want to replace certian columns in a csv file into another and i found this in the csvtoll man page. Which replaces column 1 in the first file with the column 1 in the second file.

```
csvtool pastecol 1 1 file1.csv file2.csv 
csvtool pastecol 5 3 file1.csv file2.csv
csvtool pastecol 8 8 file1.csv file2.csv
```

Is it possible to implement this into a python script?

```
import csv
csvtool pastecol 1 1 /path/file1.csv /path/file2.csv > /path/output.csv
csvtool pastecol 5 3 /path/file1.csv /path/file2.csv > /path/output.csv
csvtool pastecol 8 8 /path/file1.csv /path/file2.csv > /path/output.csv
```

and use ./csv.py to run it and have it all updated into the new file output.csv

Comment: Do you need only python solution? It possible simple add all this commands in bash file and run it from shell.

Comment: use the `subprocess` python module!

Comment: @S_Flash a bash file would also work

Comment: @S_Flash, when running the script I get this error " Fatal error: exception Invalid_argument("List.map2")" are you familiar with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case bash, as you told in comments.. You can create file like:

```
#!/bin/bash
csvtool pastecol 1 1 /path/file1.csv /path/file2.csv > /path/output.csv
csvtool pastecol 5 3 /path/file1.csv /path/file2.csv > /path/output.csv
csvtool pastecol 8 8 /path/file1.csv /path/file2.csv > /path/output.csv
```

Save it, for example like **somefile**. Then change rights to run it:

```
chmod 755 somefile
```

And run:

```
./somefile
```